# Explanation about Javascript function inside function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been learning about js for a while, I almost understand about its main concepts such as prototype, oop ... however I can't understand how this works:

```
User.findOne().where('socialid').equals(id).where('socialnetwork').equals(snw).exec(function (arr,data) {
    if(data){
    res.send(data);
    }
});
```

What I don't understand is how **data** and **arr** variables are passed to the *function* inside the *exec()* function. Is it a closure ? Can anybody give a more simple and intuitive example how it execute behind the scene ?

**EDITED**: actually, I do understand the callback behavior, what I can't understand is **data** supposed to be a result by **User.findOne()....** not from inside the callback function of **exec()** and it only passed the new function to the **exec()** as I can see in the code.

Thank you so much

Comment: Why are you all downvoting the question ? We were all new once...

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand the API you're using, and that you should read the documentation of whatever DSL that is.

Comment: Thanks Patsy, such a nice comment.

Comment: Hi Matt, I just wants to understand deeper under the hood, I totally understand the API (express.js in this case) but as I am still new to js so I can't really understand what's going under the hood of that function.

Comment: Under the hood of which function? Have you read the relevant part of the source code yet? If not, why not? If so, what didn't you understand?

Comment: Hi Matt, as my understanding, the function User.findOne()..... will return a data object, but I don't understand how that object is passed to the exec() and then processed by the function inside it. If it's a callback, the params should be inside the exec() function. I am not sure if I understand correctly or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code of `exec` will look something like this:

```
function exec(someCallback) {
    // ...
    var arr = /* ? */;
    var data = /* ? */;

    someCallback(arr, data);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the answer, actually, I do understand the callback behavior, what I can't understand is data supposed to be a result by User.findOne().... not from inside the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

Returning a value and calling a callback with the value are actually pretty similar! The fancy name for it is [Continuation Passing Style](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ContinuationPassingStyle) and in fact some programming languages have features (LISP's call/cc, C#'s async, etc) that let you write code in "regular style" but compile it down to continuation-passing-style behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Those are regular parameters.

They are passed when the inner function is called, the same way that any other function is called.

Closures refer to the fact that the inner function can access variables from the outer function (eg, `res`)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers, I understood the concept, and here are the example I want to share for other guys:

```
  function Person(){};

  Person.prototype = {
    constructor: Person,
    name : "Nicholas",
    age : 29,
    job : "Software Engineer",
    friends : ["Shelby", "Court"],
    sayName : function () {
      console.log(this.name);
    },
    hello : function (callback) {
      console.log('calling back');
      age = this.age; 
      callback(age); //we can use this.age, but for learning purpose, this' better.
    }
  };
  var person1 = new Person();
  person1.hello(function(age){console.log(age + 50);})
```

So, the **age** param was identified in the callback.

Cheers